# How to use FontAwesome unicode value and name together?

Tags: java, android, fonts

I have included FontAwesome in my Android project. I want a button to have icon and text besides. For this, I am using FontAwesome. For example, I have a wifi button and I want the text to be the icon for wifi which value is "&#xfleb;" and the text WIFI after the icon or something like "&#xfleb; WiFi". The problem is that I get two wifi icons side by side as the button text because the text is the same with the name of the icon. How to escape the text?

This is my Android Studio strings file

```
<string name="wifiButton">&#xf1eb;WiFi</string>
```

and below is how I am calling it

```
Typeface awsome = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Fonts/Awesome5.otf");
wifidetect.setTypeface(awsome);
        wifidetect.setText(R.string.wifiButton);
```

the result is two wifi icons side by side. I need to be the wifi icon first and then the text "WIFI".

Or for example like this menu icon followed by text MENU
[image]